# Pipe not sending messages between two processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

I have two processes in python using the `multiprocessing` library that are both pointed at member functions of two different objects and looks like the following:

```
 def start(self):
     # start the consumer
     conn1, conn2 = Pipe()

     p1 = Process(target=self.myClassOne.classFunction(conn1))
     p2 = Process(target=self.myClassTwo.classFunction(conn2))

     p1.start()
     p2.start()
```

**myClassOne.classFunction looks like this:**

```
for msg in array:
    pipe.send("test")
```

**myClassTwo.classFunction looks like this:**

```
while(True):
            print(pipe.recv())
```

I'm not receiving any data between the two and i'm certain data is arriving in the classOne function.  It's worth mentioning that the "array" above is actually a Kafka consumer that is populating with messages.  What am I missing here?  (The contents of the two functions are simplified examples meant solely for testing of the structure prior to adding more logic).  There is a large amount of data flowing in from the myClassOneFunction and I want to be able to parse that data in real time as it comes in without interrupting the capture process.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why use a process pipe rather than another Kafka topic? Have you heard of Faust library?

Comment: *I want to be able to parse that data in real time as it comes in without interrupting the capture process* - Any Kafka consumer loop is always blocking, so the processing thread is going to be waiting anyway

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, and `while(True):` should be written `while True:`, this isn't Java, eh.